# Make all object props be in different lines if any is on a different line in ESlint

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

am struggling with a config for eslint and basically what i want to achieve is in a destructuring statement, if any of the properties is on new line, then all should be on separate lines, the same for imports and destructured objects, e.g.

```
// is okay
import { sub1, sub2 } from 'package';
const { item1, item2 } from variable;
```

```
// is okay
import {
  sub1,
  sub2,
} from 'package';
const {
  item1,
  item2,
} from variable;

// not okay
import {
  sub1, sub2,
} from 'package';
const {
  item1, item2,
} = variable;
```

Now I have seen similar questions and from the accepted answers, here is a part of my eslint

```
'object-property-newline': [
  'error',
  {
    allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine: false,
  }
],

'object-curly-newline': [
  'error',
  {
    multiline: true,
    minProperties: 3,
    consistent: true,
  },
],
```

Basically at best these configs just get me the curly braces to be on separate lines but the props themselves are just lined up in the same line, any help on this that will work on all imports, objects definition and destructuring would be highly appreciated

Comment: Isn't reformatting more in the domain of prettier than eslint?

Comment: i hadn't thought about that, will try it out

Comment: @cefn i tried out prettier integration and it works fine, still going through code to see the styles but it works magic so far, you can put it as an answer and i accept it